# Spring data couchbase 3.0.9 release - com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException View person/all does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using Spring boot 2.0.4 with couchbase server (enterprise 5.5) as a docker container on my local machine. I have a configuration class which extends `AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration`, where I have provided the couchbase cluster/bucket details.

The repository interface is annotated with `@N1qlPrimaryIndexed` and `@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "person", viewName = "all")` and my application.properties file has `spring.data.couchbase.auto-index=true`

From what I understand, Spring boot should be able to auto create the primary index and views.

This is my config class

```
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
@Value("${couchbase_host}")
private String hostname;

@Value("${couchbase_bucket}")
private String bucket;

@Override
@Bean(name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_CLUSTER_INFO)
public ClusterInfo couchbaseClusterInfo() throws Exception {
    return couchbaseCluster().authenticate("Administrator","password").clusterManager().info();
}
@Bean
public Cluster cluster() {
    return CouchbaseCluster.create(getEnvironment(),hostname);
}
@Override
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close", name = BeanNames.COUCHBASE_BUCKET)
public Bucket couchbaseClient() throws Exception {
    return couchbaseCluster().openBucket(getBucketName());
}

@Override
protected List<String> getBootstrapHosts() {
    return Collections.singletonList(hostname);
}

@Override
protected String getBucketName() {
    return bucket;
}

@Override
protected String getBucketPassword() {
    return "password";
}

@Override
protected CouchbaseEnvironment getEnvironment() {
    CouchbaseEnvironment environment = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
                                        .connectTimeout(25000)
                                        .queryTimeout(75000)
                                        .kvTimeout(5000)
                                        .socketConnectTimeout(40000)
                                        .build();
    return environment;
}
```

When I start my app based on the above config,

```
2018-08-10 19:47:31.653  INFO 29198 --- [           main] i.InspectionsAggregateServiceApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-08-10 19:47:31.697  INFO 29198 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@757acd7b: startup date [Fri Aug 10 19:47:31 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-10 19:47:32.283  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'requestContextFilter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=requestContextFilter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=requestContextFilter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2018-08-10 19:47:32.463  INFO 29198 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2018-08-10 19:47:32.836  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-08-10 19:47:32.856  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                  : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-08-10 19:47:32.856  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                   : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-08-10 19:47:32.859  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.AprLifecycleListener             : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/lakshmananraman/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-08-10 19:47:32.965  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                        : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-08-10 19:47:32.966  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader                    : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1272 ms
2018-08-10 19:47:33.215  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean        : Servlet com.ge.trans.rc360.inspection.config.JerseyConfig mapped to [/api/*]
2018-08-10 19:47:33.218  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean        : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-08-10 19:47:33.221  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-10 19:47:33.221  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-10 19:47:33.221  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-10 19:47:33.221  INFO 29198 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean         : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-08-10 19:47:33.444  INFO 29198 --- [           main] c.c.c.c.CouchbaseCore                    : CouchbaseEnvironment: {sslEnabled=false, sslKeystoreFile='null', sslTruststoreFile='null', sslKeystorePassword=false, sslTruststorePassword=false, sslKeystore=null, sslTruststore=null, bootstrapHttpEnabled=true, bootstrapCarrierEnabled=true, bootstrapHttpDirectPort=8091, bootstrapHttpSslPort=18091, bootstrapCarrierDirectPort=11210, bootstrapCarrierSslPort=11207, ioPoolSize=8, computationPoolSize=8, responseBufferSize=16384, requestBufferSize=16384, kvServiceEndpoints=1, viewServiceEndpoints=12, queryServiceEndpoints=12, searchServiceEndpoints=12, configPollInterval=2500, configPollFloorInterval=50, ioPool=NioEventLoopGroup, kvIoPool=null, viewIoPool=null, searchIoPool=null, queryIoPool=null, coreScheduler=CoreScheduler, memcachedHashingStrategy=DefaultMemcachedHashingStrategy, eventBus=DefaultEventBus, packageNameAndVersion=couchbase-java-client/2.5.9 (git: 2.5.9, core: 1.5.9), retryStrategy=BestEffort, maxRequestLifetime=75000, retryDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=100, upper=100000}, reconnectDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MILLISECONDS, powers of 2; lower=32, upper=4096}, observeIntervalDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=10, upper=100000}, keepAliveInterval=30000, continuousKeepAliveEnabled=true, keepAliveErrorThreshold=4, keepAliveTimeout=2500, autoreleaseAfter=2000, bufferPoolingEnabled=true, tcpNodelayEnabled=true, mutationTokensEnabled=false, socketConnectTimeout=40000, callbacksOnIoPool=false, disconnectTimeout=25000, requestBufferWaitStrategy=com.couchbase.client.core.env.DefaultCoreEnvironment$2@6b760460, certAuthEnabled=false, coreSendHook=null, forceSaslPlain=false, queryTimeout=75000, viewTimeout=75000, searchTimeout=75000, analyticsTimeout=75000, kvTimeout=5000, connectTimeout=25000, dnsSrvEnabled=false}
2018-08-10 19:47:33.701  INFO 29198 --- [      cb-io-1-1] c.c.c.c.n.Node                           : Connected to Node 127.0.0.1/localhost
2018-08-10 19:47:33.750  INFO 29198 --- [      cb-io-1-1] c.c.c.c.n.Node                           : Disconnected from Node 127.0.0.1/localhost
2018-08-10 19:47:34.146  INFO 29198 --- [      cb-io-1-2] c.c.c.c.n.Node                           : Connected to Node 127.0.0.1/localhost
2018-08-10 19:47:34.208  INFO 29198 --- [-computations-4] c.c.c.c.c.ConfigurationProvider          : Opened bucket person
2018-08-10 19:47:34.459  WARN 29198 --- [           main] c.c.c.c.e.CoreEnvironment                : More than 1 Couchbase Environments found (2), this can have severe impact on performance and stability. Reuse environments!
2018-08-10 19:47:34.460  INFO 29198 --- [           main] c.c.c.c.CouchbaseCore                    : CouchbaseEnvironment: {sslEnabled=false, sslKeystoreFile='null', sslTruststoreFile='null', sslKeystorePassword=false, sslTruststorePassword=false, sslKeystore=null, sslTruststore=null, bootstrapHttpEnabled=true, bootstrapCarrierEnabled=true, bootstrapHttpDirectPort=8091, bootstrapHttpSslPort=18091, bootstrapCarrierDirectPort=11210, bootstrapCarrierSslPort=11207, ioPoolSize=8, computationPoolSize=8, responseBufferSize=16384, requestBufferSize=16384, kvServiceEndpoints=1, viewServiceEndpoints=12, queryServiceEndpoints=12, searchServiceEndpoints=12, configPollInterval=2500, configPollFloorInterval=50, ioPool=NioEventLoopGroup, kvIoPool=null, viewIoPool=null, searchIoPool=null, queryIoPool=null, coreScheduler=CoreScheduler, memcachedHashingStrategy=DefaultMemcachedHashingStrategy, eventBus=DefaultEventBus, packageNameAndVersion=couchbase-java-client/2.5.9 (git: 2.5.9, core: 1.5.9), retryStrategy=BestEffort, maxRequestLifetime=75000, retryDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=100, upper=100000}, reconnectDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MILLISECONDS, powers of 2; lower=32, upper=4096}, observeIntervalDelay=ExponentialDelay{growBy 1.0 MICROSECONDS, powers of 2; lower=10, upper=100000}, keepAliveInterval=30000, continuousKeepAliveEnabled=true, keepAliveErrorThreshold=4, keepAliveTimeout=2500, autoreleaseAfter=2000, bufferPoolingEnabled=true, tcpNodelayEnabled=true, mutationTokensEnabled=false, socketConnectTimeout=40000, callbacksOnIoPool=false, disconnectTimeout=25000, requestBufferWaitStrategy=com.couchbase.client.core.env.DefaultCoreEnvironment$2@1a87b51, certAuthEnabled=false, coreSendHook=null, forceSaslPlain=false, queryTimeout=75000, viewTimeout=75000, searchTimeout=75000, analyticsTimeout=75000, kvTimeout=5000, connectTimeout=25000, dnsSrvEnabled=false}
2018-08-10 19:47:34.569  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-10 19:47:34.681  INFO 29198 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@757acd7b: startup date [Fri Aug 10 19:47:31 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-10 19:47:34.734  INFO 29198 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-08-10 19:47:34.735  INFO 29198 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-10 19:47:34.754  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-10 19:47:34.755  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping        : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-10 19:47:34.922  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-10 19:47:34.955  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer              : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

I notice that it connects and disconnects to the node and displays the warning, found more than one couchbase environment. 
Although, the bucket is open, spring does not create the view and index and my app fails.

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: View 
person/all does not exist.; nested exception is 
com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException: View 
person/all does not exist.
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject.class
2018-08-10 19:47:35.115  INFO 29198 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@757acd7b: startup date [Fri Aug 10 19:47:31 CDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-10 19:47:35.116  INFO 29198 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-08-10 19:47:35.123  INFO 29198 --- [           main] c.c.c.c.c.ConfigurationProvider          : Closed bucket person
2018-08-10 19:47:35.123  INFO 29198 --- [      cb-io-1-2] c.c.c.c.n.Node                           : Disconnected from Node 127.0.0.1/localhost
```

Please help me understand why spring finds two couchbase environments and is not creating the primary index and view as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After re-reading the docs again, I added a override on `IndexManager` method and after overriding the other methods, spring configured the environment correctly.