# View Does Not Exist Exception in Couchbase Spring Application. View does not exists

Tags: exception, view, couchbase

I am creating a simple Spring MVC application and trying to using Couchbase(No Sql Database) in the back-end. The server is starting successfully, but when I was hitting to get something from Database, the ".InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: View todo/all does not exist.; nested exception is com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException: View todo/all does not exist." is coming.

Already tried this approach, but it is not working in my case.

Tried overriding the below method:

```
public IndexManager indexManager() {
        return new IndexManager(true, false, false);    //auto indexing 
 }
```

[Spring data couchbase 3.0.9 release - com.couchbase.client.java.error.ViewDoesNotExistException View person/all does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51795769/spring-data-couchbase-3-0-9-release-com-couchbase-client-java-error-viewdoesno)